# What caused (0) Abnormal termination (signal 11) in Condor

Tags: condor

When running a python script in HTCondor, the job terminated with the following error code in the .log file:

```
006 (4069.000.000) 02/19 15:02:29 Image size of job updated: 1393668
        1362  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)
        1393668  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
006 (4069.000.000) 02/19 15:03:12 Image size of job updated: 33197416
        1430  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)
        1463300  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
005 (4069.000.000) 02/19 15:03:12 Job terminated.
        (0) Abnormal termination (signal 11)
        (0) No core file
                Usr 0 00:00:09, Sys 0 00:00:40  -  Run Remote Usage
                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Local Usage
                Usr 0 00:00:09, Sys 0 00:00:40  -  Total Remote Usage
                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Local Usage
        0  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
        4477484  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
        0  -  Total Bytes Sent By Job
        4477484  -  Total Bytes Received By Job
        Partitionable Resources :    Usage  Request Allocated
           Cpus                 :                 1         1
           Disk (KB)            :     4500     4500   1699801
           Gpus                 :                           0
           Memory (MB)          :     1430        5         5
...
```

What can cause such an error and how to correct for it?

After Googling it I found a mialing list suggesting to add the line

```
getenv=true
```

on the submit file, which I did but that didn't solve the problem and I received the same error.

Thank you for your help/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Signal 11 refers to [SIGSEGV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) which is segmentation fault. The log message is saying that your script terminated because it had a segmentation fault, there is nothing Condor can do. You need to debug your script to make sure it doesn't do invalid memory accesses etc that will cause segfaults.

I would also add notification in the job description file if the Condor is setup correctly:

```
notification = Error
notify_user = my@email.com
```

Such that in these cases it will notify you that your job terminated abnormally.